# Echarts React: Create dataset with multiple values per cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I am trying to create a [dataset](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/concepts/dataset) in Echarts for React that includes both scatter and bar plot data in order to do cross filtering.

The dataset for the scatter plot is a 2d array in the following format:

```
const dataset = [
  ['Q1_x', 'Q1_y'],
  [30, 50],
  [22, 43],
  [11, 77],
];
```

I have multiple choice questions where I want to display the count for each choice in a bar plot.

For example the question: What ice cream flavor is your favorite? (can select more than one)

1. Strawberry
2. Vanilla
3. Chocolate

In the JSON it has the following format (for two responses):

```
const responses = [
  {
    labels: {
      QID19: ['Strawberry', 'Vanilla'],
    },
  },
  {
    labels: {
      QID19: ['Chocolate'],
    },
  },
];
```

As you can see in the JSON, when more than one option is selected, it's an array.

I know how to get the counts of each option.

My specific question is how to include that in the main dataset that I have for the scatter above?
Should each option in the MCQ be a separate column (i.e., dimension)? Or should I join the array items into one string and include that as a cell in the dataset?

I want to eventually be able to cross-filter. For example, select only the scatter plots where the person selected "Chocolate" in the bar plot.

Any advice on how to proceed is appreciated. I'm looking for a general direction on implementation in Echarts (not necessarily specific code)